How to hide controls, showinfo, modestbranding and rel in my youtube embeded video?
I want to hide all the below points in my youtube embeded link but it is not working at all. How to do it? Had researched but could not get anything which can help me with this.
Let me know if it is possible or not?

autoplay=1: Autoplay the video
mute=1: Mute the video
loop=1: Loop the video
controls=0: Hide video controls
showinfo=0: Hide video title and player actions
modestbranding=1: Hide YouTube logo
rel=0: Disable related videos

 <div className="w-screen">
      <iframe
       className="w-screen aspect-video"
        src={"https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + movieTrailer?.key+"?autoplay=1&mute=1&loop=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1&rel=0"}
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
      ></iframe>
    </div>


As far as I know, it is not possible hide such controls/elements with the settings YouTube has. You have to use another methods - can't be sure if CSS override can be applied, You have to search and find out.

@MauricioAriasOlave thanks, will check another alternative for this
